# How can I filter a collection based on a day (rather than a date)?

Tags: php, database, magento, entity-attribute-value

The end goal here is to get a list of customers whose birthday is today and send out a voucher code to them (which is also done programmatically).

To do this, I need to grab all customers with a birthday today.  In SQL I would convert the `date` into a day and month and query that, but I'm unsure how to do that in a collection.  Currently I have:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->joinAttribute('dob','customer/dob', 'entity_id');
        ->addAttributeToFilter('dob', '2015-10-02 00:00:00');
```

This only matches people with a DOB on 2/10/2015.  In this example, I need to match everyone with a date of birth of 2nd October, not just 2nd October 2015.  So, how can I omit the year and just include the day and month?

I have been able to achieve this using a LIKE, but that seems unoptimised and I'd like to assume there's a far better way of doing this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->joinAttribute('dob','customer/dob', 'entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('dob', array('like' => '%-10-02 00:00:00'));
```

Comment: I suppose your dob field has a kind of date property so don't use like, use   a date function in your sql. (which one depends on your database)

Comment: @Terradon: Yes I know, that's what the question is - how can I do that in a collection?

Comment: For example in MySQL: DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d') So in your collection i think it becomes ('dob', array('like' => DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d'). I assume you have used a real date column and you just need a sql function of your database to set a right format for TODAY.or NOW,

Comment: If you want it to be optimized, you need to add a day+month (without year) key to your db (otherwise, it will iterate over all records and filter). But i'm not sure it worth to do.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be like this Implement query as per your need logic is here:

```
SELECT
  emp_firstname AS first_name,
  emp_lastname AS last_name,
  emp_birthday AS dob
FROM
  emp
WHERE
  MONTH(emp_birthday)=MONTH(CURDATE())
  AND DAY(emp_birthday)=DAY(CURDATE())
or if you want to consider also leap years, you could use this:

SELECT
  emp_firstname AS first_name,
  emp_lastname AS last_name,
  emp_birthday AS dob
FROM
  emp
WHERE
  emp_birthday +
    INTERVAL
      YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(emp_birthday) +
      (MONTH(emp_birthday)<MONTH(CURDATE())
       OR (MONTH(emp_birthday)=MONTH(CURDATE()) AND DAY(emp_birthday)<DAY(CURDATE())))
    YEAR = CURDATE()
If someone's date of birth is on 29th of February, and today is 28th of February and this year is not a leap year, my last query will consider his/her birthday as today.

My second query could be also simplified like this:

SELECT
  emp_firstname AS first_name,
  emp_lastname AS last_name,
  emp_birthday AS dob
FROM
  emp
WHERE
  (MONTH(emp_birthday)=MONTH(CURDATE())
  AND DAY(emp_birthday)=DAY(CURDATE()))
  OR (DAY(LAST_DAY(emp_birthday))=29
      AND DAY(emp_birthday)=29
      AND DAY(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()))=28);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's nothing to do with Magento collections.  It's just SQL, which is the easy part of the problem - I need ot know how to implement that within a Magento collection

Answer (score 0):

```
solution:


require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('dob', array('lteq' => $currentDate));


foreach ($customerCollection as $customer) {
    $active = $customer->getIsActive();
    if($active == 1){
        //echo 'customer Dob => '.$customer->getDob().'<br>';
        $customerDob = $customer->getDob();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        $date =  date('d/m',  strtotime($customerDob));
        echo $customerId.' => '.$date.'<br>';
    }

}
```

Comment: That isnt querying for everyone whose birthday it is today, that's getting everyone and then looping through checking their DOB. On a store with thousands of customers that is horrendously unoptimised